# Get authors of methods, like codelens

Tags: git, visual-studio, codelens

I need to get authors of methods list. 
I've tried to do it by comparing methods name with patches content by using LibGit2Sharp, but it's too long, there are to many commits.
I wanted to do it quickly, somehow like code lens. 
Now I'm trying to get it by own VS plugin, may be there are some easyer ways. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `git blame filename` output. It seems LibGit2Sharp [supports](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/492) this. You can run it for specific method if you know the line numbers where method starts and ends e.g. by running `git blame -L 1,10 filename` you will see who was the last changing lines 1-10 in a file.

Comment: Blame doesn't work perfect. 
Sometimes it can't get initial commit.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have VS 2013 Ultimate installed so can't experiment with codelens functionality to see how exactly it finds the author of a method. The only assumption I have is that it runs `git blame` for specific lines of file, then look for a most popular editor of those lines.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I've found that git log --follow is more correct :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a code sample of searching by blame:

```
var blames = repo.Blame(parameters.FilePath.Replace(_repository, ""));
var commitDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var blame in blames)
{
    if (blame.InitialCommit.Sha != (blame.InitialCommit.Parents.FirstOrDefault() == null ? blame.InitialCommit.Sha : blame.InitialCommit.Parents.First().Sha) &&
        (!blame.InitialCommit.Message.ToLower().Contains("merge")))
    {
        Tree commitTree1 = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(blame.InitialCommit.Sha).Tree;
        Tree commitTree2 = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(blame.InitialCommit.Parents.FirstOrDefault() == null ? blame.InitialCommit.Sha : blame.InitialCommit.Parents.First().Sha).Tree;
        string content = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(commitTree1, commitTree2).Content;
        if (content.Contains(parameters.TestName))
        {
            if (commitDate.CompareTo(blame.InitialSignature.When.Date) > 0)
            {
                commitDate = blame.InitialSignature.When.Date;
                author = string.Format("Email: {0}; Name: {1}", blame.InitialCommit.Author.Email, blame.InitialCommit.Author.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```